# Non integer solutions to mod

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I have the question:
Solve simultaneously the three congruences 3x≡4(mod 7), 4x≡5(mod 8) and 5x≡6(mod 9).
I have found solutions to the first one and last one, which are x≡6(mod 7) and x≡3(mod 9). However, the middle one is giving me some trouble as using the division rule I would have x≡1.25(mod 2), which would not make sense with the other congruences.

Comment: Congruences are only defined for integers.

Comment: As you have noticed, $4x\equiv 5\pmod 8$ is impossible.   Indeed, if $8\,|\,(4x-5)$ for some integer $x$ then we could deduce  $4\,|\,5$, a contradiction.

Comment: Also, what is the "division rule"?

Comment: If there are integers $x,y$ with $4x+8y=5$ then $5$ is even, contradiction.